# graphql-query an array/plain object result？

Tags: reactjs, graphql, graphql-js

```js
const data = {
  items: [
    { a: 'a' },
    { b: 'b' }
  ]
}
```

say we want to query `data.items` without specifying field names(`a`, `b`) under `items`, can we achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You cannot query `data.items` without specifying atleast one subfield of items. If you want to share that type across multiple queries, you can define it as a fragment and share that fragment across multiple queries to avoid duplication of type.

For example you can create and reuse a fragment as follows

```
const itemFragment = gql`
  fragment item on items {
    a: String
    b: String
  }
`

export const data = gql`
  query data {
    data {
      ...itemFragment
    }
  }
  ${itemFragment}
`;
```